# Programmatically adding HttpSessionListener to Jetty not working

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using Jetty 9 embedded and try to use `ServletContext.addListener(T)` to add a `HttpSessionListener` from within my `Servlet.init()` method. However, the methods on my session listener don't ever get called. At the same time, when I let my listener class implement `ServletRequestListener`, the request listener related methods get called. I do call `getSession()`, so session creation should be triggered.

Any Ideas, workarounds? Am I misreading the spec? Known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServletContext.addListener()` is only supported (per spec) in a narrow scope.

It can be used from one of the 2 code paths.

1. [`ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup-java.util.Set-javax.servlet.ServletContext-)
2. [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-)

All other uses of `ServletContext.addListener()` are invalid.